# How To Import External Library to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I would like to extract features of images using opencv 3.0 with Visual Studio 2013.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d.hpp"
#include <opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

void readme();

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        readme(); return -1;
    }

    Mat img_1 = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img_2 = imread(argv[2], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!img_1.data || !img_2.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
    }

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 400;

    Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(minHessian);

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

    detector->detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
    detector->detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

    //-- Draw keypoints
    Mat img_keypoints_1; Mat img_keypoints_2;

    drawKeypoints(img_1, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
    drawKeypoints(img_2, keypoints_2, img_keypoints_2, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

    //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
    imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1);
    imshow("Keypoints 2", img_keypoints_2);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

/** @function readme */
void readme()
{
    std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_detector <img1> <img2>" << std::endl;
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp': No such file or directory
```

In  C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\include\opencv2

directory, there is no xfeatures2d.hpp file. Thus, I should import this library externally. How to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you did not build opencv 3.0 with [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib)?

Comment: I kept track of the instructions in that link. I applied those commands:            `cd C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build                                                         cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\opencv_contrib-master\modules C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\sources`                                         It creates an CMakeError.txt file including lots of errors.

Comment: Please post the CMakeError.txt file